# How to add time in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I need to add time in a [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) using jQuery and JavaScript. I am explaining my code below.

```
<input class="form-control" name="startgroupdate" id="stdate" type="text" placeholder=""  onfocus="removeBorder('stdate')">
```

```js
$('input[name="startgroupdate"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    drops: "up",
    minDate: '01/01/2012',
    maxDate: '12/31/2017'
});
```

Here only the date is coming from the calendar, but I need to add also the time, so the result should be like "03/04/2017 12 10 PM".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out..You need to add time property and daterangepicker js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link href="daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="moment.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.25/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input class="form-control" name="startgroupdate" id="stdate" type="text" placeholder="">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="startgroupdate"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        locale: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        },
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        drops: "down",
        minDate: '01/01/2012',
        maxDate: '12/31/2017'
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did as per you but the date only reflecting on input field but along with time is not coming.

Comment: No,same issue. Where you did the changes.

Comment: There are couple of changes, please check with updated code..Its working in my system..If you using document.ready function, please make sure you add above code in it and remove auto function from above code.

Comment: Let me to create one plunkr and share with you.

Comment: Please check this link [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/yqmaYTs61TY9NMFELYB4?p=preview).

Comment: You might also need to day start and end using: `moment().subtract('days', 0).startOf('day'), moment().subtract('days', 0).endOf('day')`

Answer (score 2):

Yo have to add property

```
 timePicker: true
```

may this links helps
https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example2

Comment: Best answer!Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the timepicker flag to daterangepicker.

```
$('input[name="startgroupdate"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true  
    drops: "up",
    minDate: '01/01/2012',
    maxDate: '12/31/2017'
});
```